# INSERT INTO SELECT with LEFT JOIN not preventing duplicates for simultaneous hits

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions, duplicates, left-join

I have this SQL query that inserts records from one table to another without duplicates.

It works fine, if I call this SQL query from one instance of my application. But in production, the application is horizontally scaled, having more than one instance of application, each calling below query simultaneously at the same time. That is causing duplicate records to me. Is there any way to fix this query, so it allows simultaneous hits?

```
INSERT INTO table1 (col1, col2)
    SELECT DISTINCT TOP 10
        t2.col1, 
        t2.col2 
    FROM   
        table2 t2 
    LEFT JOIN 
        table1 t1 ON t2.col1 = t1.col1 
                  AND t2.col2 = t1.col2 
    WHERE  
        t1.col1 IS NULL
```

Comment: Use a `HOLDLOCK, UPDLOCK` hint on the second reference to `table1`. Also there are some weird things about this query: Why `DISTINCT`, why do you think you will get duplicates (from the *source* table)? Why `TOP 10` with no `ORDER BY`, you may get different results each time. `LEFT JOIN...IS NULL` is better written as a `NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1`

Comment: _hat is causing duplicate records to me_ Then you need a primary key or unique constraint to fix it. Focus on the real problem first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The corrective action here depends on the behavior you want.  If you intend to allow for just a single horizontal instance of your application to execute this query, then you need to create a critical section, into which one instance is allowed to enter.  Since you are already using SQL Server, you could implement by forcing each instance to get a lock on a certain table.  Only the instance which gets the lock will execute the query, and the others will drop off.

If, on the other hand, you really want each instance to execute the query, then you should use a *serializable* transaction.  Using a serializable transaction will ensure that only one instance can do the insert on the table at a given time.  It would not be possible for two or more instances to interleave and execute the same insert.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I will explore on the lock on one instance option, instead of serializable transaction, as I feel serializable could cause dead locks.